# MDX for get after 6 month last date from today. ex, 2019-02-28

Tags: sql-server, ssis, mdx

I wrote a mdx to ssis variable i need to get current date to 6 month + last date
2019-02-28. but query shown its 2019-02-31 how can i fix this. my code is

```
(DT_WSTR, 10) DATEPART("YYYY", DATEADD("M", 6, GETDATE())) 
   + "-" + RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 10) DATEPART("MM" , DATEADD("M", 6, GETDATE())), 2)   
   + "-" + RIGHT( "0" + (DT_STR, 6 ,1252) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("dd", - day(getdate()), GETDATE())), 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DATEADD("dd", - 1, DATEADD("M", 7, GETDATE()))` for get last day of the month. Your query gives the last day of the current month.

```
(DT_WSTR, 10) DATEPART("YYYY", DATEADD("M", 6, GETDATE())) 
   + "-" + RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 10) DATEPART("MM" , DATEADD("M", 6, GETDATE())), 2)   
   + "-" + RIGHT( "0" + (DT_STR, 6 ,1252) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("dd", - day(getdate()), DATEADD("M", 7, GETDATE()))), 2)
```

Comment: when current month is 2018-09-05 then 6+ month end date should be 2019-03-31 this not sustainable for that one? right?